# Create a fully transparent WPF window to capture mouse events

Tags: wpf, mouse, transparency

I'm trying to trap mouse events in WPF by using a topmost, transparent non-modal window.  I'm finding that this works fine if the opacity of the window is 0.01 or greater and it has a background color, but when the opacity is set to 0 it no longer receives mouse messages.  Is there a way make this window look fully transparent and still get mouse input?

Comment: Transparent windows can cause problems in general, I'm a bit curious why you went with this approach. I understand 3.5 SP1 resolved some of the major issues, but still it's a pretty heavy duty way to trap mouse input. I you can already take over the screen maybe it would be better to do this within the application window itself?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As far as I know, no.

When a `Control` or `Window` is fully transparent, it can then be clicked through. This is the case if you set your `Window.Background="Transparent"`, or `Opacity="0"`. As far as I know, this is by design in WPF.

When using an opacity of 0.01, you should barely see the window, if at all. This is likely your best bet at achieving the functionality.

**Edit:** Another solution, which I tried and does work, is to set the background color to an almost-transparent color. I used `Background="#01000000"`, thus giving an alpha value of 1. This makes your window background transparent-looking, but allows you to place controls on it with the window at full opacity.

Comment: See my edit for a different solution. You can change the background to a near-transparent color, and still keep your window at full opacity incase you want to overlay some controls on the screen.

Comment: The second solution does work but it looks the same as setting the Opacity to 0.01.

Comment: Are you able to see it? On my screen, it looked completely transparent, I couldn't tell the difference. It should look the same for the most part, the only difference is you can overlay non-transparent things. Since I'm not sure what you're using this for, not sure what the best solution was.

Comment: Actually, even a fully transparent color value works - I use #00000000 for this purpose. It works because Opacity is not 0, and the brush is a solidcolorbrush - the alpha value doesn't seem to be cosidered. Brushes.Transparent also works because it's simply a #00FFFFFF solidcolorbrush

Comment: @Egor: When I was trying this, transparent brushes caused the Window to be click-through. This was on .NET 3.5 SP1... so maybe a different version?

Comment: @Egor I had to set Background to #01000000 too in .NET 4.5.

Comment: @Egor I think you missed the point of the original question, a value of #00000000 will always make the clicks pass through the window, unless you click on an actual control.

Answer (score 12):

In Visual Studio 2010:
Select your window in your design view.

Set the properties of your window to:

- AllowsTransparency : check it
- Background : Transparent
- WindowStyle : None

Comment: @JMK Because this makes clicks pass through the Window, unless you hit an actual Control inside the Window.

Comment: The key for me was "AllowsTransparency"

Answer (score 3):

Just set Background=Brushes.Transparent instead of Background=null.

You don't need to use opacity at all (ie. just leave it at 100% opacity).

Comment: I tried this out, thinking the same possibility, but it doesn't work. When the Background is transparent, clicks are not captured by the program, instead grabbing whatever program is underneath.

Comment: Can you show an example? I use this approach (generally #00000000 because it's so easy to type) and it seems to work just fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

For example i think your control name is `MyGrid` and you want it be `Transparent` and always get **`MouseOverEvent`**.....

**If** (window `AllowsTransparency` is `True` **and** the window `Background` is `Transparent`) **Then**

> **use** a color like **`#01777777`** for `MyGrid` `Background` **Or** **`0.01`** for `MyGrid` `Opacity`.

**Else**

> **use** something like **`#00777777`** for `MyGrid` `Background` **Or** **`0.00`** for `MyGrid` `Opacity`.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the opacity to 100% (or any non-zero value), and the background to Transparent (instead of null) should make most controls hittable.

Make sure to set [IsHitTestVisible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ishittestvisible.aspx) to true. Not all controls can be hit, even if the opacity is 100% and the background is transparent.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but when I do a Show on a window with these settings it doesn't get displayed at all (i.e. the window's not present when you alt+tab).

Answer (score 0):

You might find it simpler to use `Mouse.Capture`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771301.aspx

> When an object captures the mouse, all mouse related events are treated as if the object with mouse capture perform the event, even if the mouse pointer is over another object.