# WPF window flickers when resizing

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a very simple window, defined with the following XAML (There is currently no logic in the View Model):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfViewer.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfViewer"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="525"
        Height="350"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:MainWindowVm}"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid Margin="8">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="8" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                    Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,8">
            <TextBlock Text="Object" />
            <!--  breadcrumbs  -->
        </StackPanel>
        <Border Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="0"
                BorderBrush="Black"
                BorderThickness="1" />
        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1"
                      Grid.Column="1"
                      Width="8"
                      Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrush}}"
                      ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext" />
        <Border Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="2"
                BorderBrush="Black"
                BorderThickness="1" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

As the user resizes the window, the new area of the window flickers black.
[image]

Is there any way to prevent this flickering?

---

I do not beleive that this existing question is a duplicate.  It involves completely custom windows, with animations.

[Prevent WPF window flicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22563416/prevent-wpf-window-flicker?rq=1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know this is old, but as the accepted answer suggests, this is because of the debugging tools. You will notice a significant performance improvement from disabling UI Debugging Tools for XAML, provided you don't use or rely on them:

> Tools > Options > Debugging > General > Enable UI Debugging Tools for XAML

and of course running the app outside of the debugger should show you the application's *actual* performance. Running your program using any IDE as a debugger will undoubtedly slow it down significantly, this is just a result of the way debuggers interact with your program, monitoring everything it does and listening for exceptions, etc.

Answer (score 3):

This is being caused by the debug-time additions to the window.  Try running it without the debugger attached.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue but I solved it by using the nuget package **edge.windowchrome** an upgraded version of Microsoft.Windows.Shell

It helped me to remove the flicker

Note: it will only work very well with latest version of Windows 10 (redstone)

Answer (score -2):

Use [**UWP Host**](https://github.com/Selastin-George/UWP-Host) it may solve your issue.

See this for sample screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

You can remove complete titlebar from here. Give the Attribute `ShowTitlebar="false"` in `mainwindow`.