# WPF Make transparent window background clickable

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a window in a WPF application with a transparent background. I want even the transparent portions to **still be clickable**. However, WPF automatically excludes the transparent parts from hit testing. Setting the window background to a slightly non-transparent color (eg. `#01000000`) **is not an option** as I need the window to be **fully and completely transparent**. How can I achieve this?

Here is the XAML definition of my window:

```xml
<Window x:Class="ScreenDropper.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ScreenDropper"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="ScreenDropper" Height="40" Width="48" Topmost="True" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" MouseLeftButtonDown="Window_MouseLeftButtonDown" Background="Transparent" Cursor="Cross">
    <Grid>
        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" CornerRadius="12" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="24" Height="24">
            <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="White" CornerRadius="12">
                <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" x:Name="InnerBorder" CornerRadius="12"></Border>
            </Border>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Seems you've already seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1646346/1136211). What other answer than those given there do you expect?

Comment: @Clemens All of those answers do not fit my needs or simply don't work (anymore). So I'd want a solution that gives me a completely (not just almost) transparent window which still can be clicked on.

Comment: But you already know that a fully transparent background won't work? I fail to see how a color value of #01000000 would in any way be a problem. Anyway, good luck.

Comment: @Clemens I am building a colour picker which gets the pixel colour underneath the cursor, and a window color of `#01000000` would falsify that result.

Comment: Sure, but that's better than not getting a color value at all. As you may conclude from the answers to the mentioned question (and others here on StackOverflow), a WPF window with AllowsTransparency will simply not receive input events at fully transparent areas.

Comment: @Clemens Is there nothing that you can do? (p/invoke for example)

Answer (score -1):

Try putting Background="Transparent" on the grid within the window, and attach a mousedown to it

Comment: This sadly does not change anything about the situation. It seems as WPF treats every transparent region as click-through.

Comment: I wonder if setting it at the top-level is what the problem is, as I've used transparent background to trap clicks before. I know a null background won't capture clicks.